# Android SDCard mounting delay

Tags: android

I have an activity in my application which is basically a gallery which displays the pictures located on my sdcard. I am using this function to remount the sdcard to scan for new images when the activity starts:

```
    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

The thing is when i do this the gallery does not show the updated images as android takes time to scan. So I put a sleep after that to wait for the scan to finish like this:

```
    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));    

    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This works but makes the application pause for 2 seconds. Is there a better way to handle this by putting a loading dialog? I'm not sure how to identify when the sdcard scan has been completed so that I can resume the activity.

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely a bad approach to take.  First, `Thread.sleep()` is something that should generally be avoided.  Second, there is no way be assured that the scan has finished (what if there are a LOT of pictures or a slow device?).

The better way is to do this asynchronously.  You can set up a [`BroadcastReciever`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to listen for [`Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED).  This intent will contain the directory you provided earlier back as the data field.